# Show that these definitions are equivalent

Tags: statistical-mechanics

1. **Consider the three definition of entropy namely
   \begin{eqnarray}
     S &\equiv& k\log\Gamma(E), \label{1.1}\\
     S &\equiv& k\log\Sigma(E), \label{1.2}\\
     S &\equiv& k\log\omega(E), \label{1.3}
     \end{eqnarray}
   where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant, and
   \begin{eqnarray}
    \Gamma(E) &\equiv& \int_{E<H(p,q)<E+\Delta}d^{3N}\!p\,d^{3N}\!q; \quad \Delta \ll E, \label{1.4}\\
    \Sigma(E) &\equiv& \int_{H(p,q)<E}d^{3N}\!p\,d^{3N}\!q, \label{1.5}\\
    \omega(E) &\equiv& \frac{\partial \Sigma(E)}{\partial E}, \label{1.6}
     \end{eqnarray}
   With $H(p,q)$ being the Hamiltonian, and $(p,q)$ the set of canonically conjugate variables. Show that the three definitions are equivalent up to additive constants of order $\log N$, where $N$ is the number of particles.**

I have already answer one part of that question.

Ans: Using the definition of $\Gamma(E)$ we get,
\begin{align}
 \Gamma(E) &\equiv \int_{E<H(p,q)<E+\Delta}d^{3N}\!p\,d^{3N}\!q \nonumber\\
 &= \int_{E<H(p,q)}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q+\int_{H(p,q)<E+\Delta}d^{3N}\!p\,d^{3N}\!q \nonumber\\
 &= -\int_{H(p,q)<E}d^{3N}pd^{3N}q+\int_{H(p,q)<E+\Delta}d^{3N}\!p\,d^{3N}\!q \nonumber\\
 &= \Sigma(E+\Delta) - \Sigma(E)
 \end{align}
Now expanding $\Sigma(E+\Delta)$ using Taylor series expansion where $\Delta \ll E$ we get,
\begin{align}
 \Sigma(E+\Delta) = \Sigma(E)+ \Delta \frac{\partial \Sigma(E)}{\partial E} + ...\label{1.8}
 \end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
 \Gamma(E) &= \Sigma(E+\Delta) - \Sigma(E) \nonumber\\
 &\approx  \Sigma(E)+ \Delta \frac{\partial \Sigma(E)}{\partial E} - \Sigma(E) \quad \mbox{[retaining only 1st order term]}\nonumber\\
 &= \Delta \frac{\partial \Sigma(E)}{\partial E} \nonumber\\
 &= \Delta \omega
 \end{align}
Therefore from definition 1 we get,
\begin{align}
 S &\equiv k\log\Gamma(E) \nonumber\\
 &\equiv k\log(\Delta \omega) \nonumber\\
 &\equiv k\log(\Delta) + k\log(\omega) \nonumber\\
 &\equiv k\log(\omega) \quad \mbox{[$\Delta$ is small . So $\log\Delta \approx 0$]}\nonumber
 \end{align}
So, definition 1 and 3 are equivalent.
Please mention how to show definition 1 and 2 are equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! For this question not to be dismissed as "do the work for me", please provide your attempt and/or the particular thing that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's show the definition 2 and 3 are equivalent. First,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial E} \log \Sigma = \frac{\omega}{\Sigma}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log \omega = \log\Sigma + \log \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial E} \log \Sigma \right).
$$
Since the second term of RHS is the order of $\log \log N$, we can neglect it.